# one regex or linq instead of current function

Tags: c#, regex, linq

```
    //=========================================================================
    ///This is the main function 
    /// Convert String to array of string patterns
    /// Clean the new array from any redundances 
    /// Get the repeated items and their repeated numbers 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="source">Original string that was generated</param> 
    /// <param name="repeatedNumber">how many items were found</param> 
    /// <param name="sequenceLength">the user input to create the string patterns</param> 
    /// <returns>the list of repeated items and their repeated numbers </returns> 

    static List<MyDataClass> GetConsecutiveChars(string source, out int repeatedNumber, int sequenceLength)
    {

        //var matchList = Regex.Matches(source, "([a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\-\\*\\&\\^\\%\\$\\#\\@\\!])\\1{" + (sequenceLength - 1) + "}").Cast<Match>()
        //                                                                                 .Select(m => m.Value)
        //                                                                                 .ToArray();
        ////var matchList = Regex.Matches(source, "([a-zA-Z0-9])\\1{" + (sequenceLength - 1) + "}").Cast<Match>()
        ////                                                                                 .Select(m => m.Value)
        ////                                                                                 .ToArray();

        //var result2 = source.GroupBy(c => c).Where(c => c.Count() >1).Select(c => new { charName = c.Key, charCount = c.Count() });
        //===========================================================================
        //Devid the source to the pieces :
        List<string> list = DistributedStringToArray(source, sequenceLength);
        //===========================================================================
        //Clean list from duplicated values
        list = (from item in list select item).Distinct().ToList();            
        //===========================================================================
        //Check if it was repeated or not 
        List<MyDataClass> result = FillListWtihRepeatedItems(source, list);
        //===========================================================================
        //Get the number of repeated items 
        repeatedNumber = 0;
        repeatedNumber = result.Count();
        //===========================================================================
        //return the list of repeated items and their repeated numbers
        return result;
    }
```

**My question**: 
Can I do all of that in one Regular expression statement or linq statment?

I tried but I couldn't. I added comments to regular expression statment and linq statment.

Please, advise me.

I uploaded my current application to https://dotnetfiddle.net/qO7PvS#run-results

Example:

```
statement is : [I like to know little]
```

The result:

```
k = 2
o = 2
i = 2
li = 2
....
```

Trying to calculate the repeated characters or words in the statement for 2 times.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include sample input and desired output.

Comment: And also tell us what you're trying to do, rather than us having to read code at doesn't work and assume what it's supposed to do?

Comment: `(from item in list select item)` is pointless, just do `list.Distinct().ToList()`.  Also most of your logic seems to be in two functions that you have not included.

Comment: Count distinct chars and count each distinct substring are quite different, and neither of them (judging by your sample data) is consecutive...

Comment: So do you think, what I did is the best solution after I update it with juharr code

Comment: “Some people, when confronted with a problem, say ‘I know, I’ll use regex.’ Now they have two problems.”

Comment: I am looking for a professional solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the most efficient, but if I try this in LINQPad:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, source.Length - 1)
          .SelectMany(l => Enumerable.Range(0, source.Length - l - 1)
                                     .Select(i => source.Substring(i, l)) )
          .GroupBy(s => s)
          .Where(g => g.Count() > 1 && !g.Key.Any(char.IsWhiteSpace))
          .Select(c => new { c.Key, Count = c.Count() })
```

I get:

```
Key Count
l   2
i   2
k   2
t   3
o   2
li  2
```

Answer (score 1):

To get consecutive characters, you need to use so called [named back reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/backreference-constructs-in-regular-expressions). It works like this:

```
(?<char>\w)\k<char>
```

For instance, the following will find consecutive `b`s:

```
var input = "aaaaabbbbbbccccc";
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"(?<char>b)\k<char>+");
```

Output: `bbbbbb`

Comment: I like to use it to display the repeated words and characters, and their numbers